# FreeRadius to Cisco ACS

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel5

I am currently trying to get a RHEL 5 machine to access a cisco acs through radius. I have the freeradius package installed and using the radtest command to attempt to reach the radius server. I am seeing the below output when I go onto the cisco radius server I am not seeing any hits to the access rule because the NAS-IP is being set by either my linux machine or the cisco ACS as the broadcast below. When I run the radtest command I am giving it the address and port number to my cisco ACS what is causing the NAS-IP to be set as a broadcast?

```
radtest test aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa <ipaddress and port 1 mysecert
Sending Access-Request of id 167 to <Ipaddress and  port>
   User-Name = "test"
   User-Password = "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
   NAS-IP-Address = 255.255.255.255
   NAS-Port = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to interact with "any" RADIUS server you'd better use the "radclient" instead of the "radtest". It will give you all the flexibility you need to send exactly the request you want. It also supports features like CoA.

See https://wiki.freeradius.org/config/Radclient for more details about how to use it. As you installed freeradius already, it should be available on your system.